# Unwanted cut words in the output

Tags: sas

I tried to submit the code below, but SAS doesn't show the complete values in the output. It would cut the word after the blank in the values of the variable "COMPLICATION".
Can anyone fix it?

```
data complication;
length SUBJECT 8 COMPLICATION $ 15.5;
  input SUBJECT COMPLICATION $ ;
  datalines;
2076  Pneumonia
3585  DVT(Lower)
3630  DVT(Lower)
4585  Compartment
4599  Aspiration
4760  Acute Resp
4775  Pneumonia
2076  Heart Attack
3585  Pneumonia
3660  Heart Attack
4585  Pneumonia
4599  Pneumonia
4760  Pneumonia
4775  DVT(Lower)
2076  Renal Fail
3585  Renal Fail
3630  Pancreatit
4585  Skin Break
4599  Renal Fail
4760  Renal Fail
4775  Pneumonia
3630  Pneumonia
4775  Renal Fail
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value (or field) separator is a space, so the character input is 'clipped' at the first space.  Use the LIST INPUT modifier `&` after a variable name to cause INPUT to use two spaces as the delimiter, and thus allow embedded single spaces in the field value.

The `LENGTH` statement should not have `$15.5` change it to `$15`.  The `INPUT` statement already knows about the `COMPLICATION` variable because it was set up with `LENGTH` in the prior statement.  So change `COMPLICATION $` to `COMPLICATION &`

So you want

```
data complication;
  length SUBJECT 8 COMPLICATION $ 15;
   input SUBJECT   COMPLICATION & ;
...
```